# Objective C, rounded corner custom window?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, window

I have a subclass of NSWindow to customize one of my windows for my app. 
I have everything set, but I am not sure how to make the corners round. 
Currently, my window is a transparent rectangular window with some buttons, labels, and a textfield in it.

The class includes:

```
#import "TransparentRoundRectWindow.h"

@implementation TransparentRoundRectWindow

-(id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag
{
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    if (self) {
        [self setAlphaValue:0.75];
        [self setOpaque:YES];
        [self setHasShadow:YES];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}
```

I just need to make the corners round now. I tried searching for similar situations and saw some of them explaining to override the drawRect method but I couldn't get them to work. 
How could I do this? 
(I'm using Mac OS X Lion)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set to Your window Opaque to NO. And subclass Your window's view.

**Window subclass:**

```
-(id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag
{
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    if (self) {

        [self setOpaque:NO];
        [self setHasShadow:YES];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow
{
    return YES;
}
```

**Window's view subclass:**

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    NSBezierPath * path;
    path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect xRadius:8 yRadius:8];

    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.75] set];
    [path fill];
}
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

**More explanation how to do this:**

Create new NSView class and paste "Window's view subclass" code which I wrote in it. Then go to Your window's view.

Here is window's view click on it:

[image: Window's view]

Go to the Identity inspector and set class to your created class:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So are those two in separate classes? I put all of them in the same class. I'm really new to Objective-c so it would be even more helpful if you could briefly explain to me more about how to add the Window's view subclass. Also, when I change the setOpaque to NO, I get a window that is completely transparent, although I want it only to be partially transparent (with alphavalue 0.75). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Dennis I added more explanation how to do this.

Comment: YES, it finally worked!! Thank you so much. Except now all the objects inside the window have that white corners. The textfield, buttons, and the label have the extra square corners. Would there be anyway to remove them? Will I have to create a subclass for each of those objects as well?

Comment: Here is bezierPathWithRoundedRect problem. Solution will be to create another custom view and place in it Your textfields, buttons and labels. Create that view smaller than your window's view (do not cover corners). In created view's drawRect method add these lines: [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.75] set]; NSRectFill([self bounds]); these will fill Your view (use always the same color like in window's view background color). That should solve this problem. Good luck Dennis!

Comment: Perfect! It works like a charm. This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!! I will go ahead and experiment more with these.